# Best practice for NSAutoreleasePool in callbacks from another thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I have a C++ library that I want to expose as an Objective-C framework, so it will be easier to use for Objective-C developers. In wrapping up the C++ library I have come across one particular problem in dealing with autorelease objects and threading.

One feature of the library is that the developer can register a "logger" for receiving notification-messages as callbacks from the library. The notification from the library use C++ types and is received from another (POSIX) thread, so I've made a private C++ wrapper class to handle this: it receives the callback, turn the char* argument into an NSString, and pass it on to an Objective-C logger instance provided by the user. This all works very well and looks something like this:

```
// Is called from the C++ library from another posix thread
void ObjCLoggerWrapper::LogMessage(const char *message)
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  // Pass string to the user-provided Objective-C instance called "Logger"
  [Logger logMessage:[[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:message] autorelease]];
  [pool release];
}
```

As an example of a user callback I wrote this simple method to collect all logging in a NSString member m_text in the user-class' instance (to be used elsewhere, but that's irrelevant).

```
-(void) logMessage: (NSString*)message
{
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    m_text = [m_text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%04d: %@\r\n", m_lineno++, message];
  }
}
```

So far so good. Or so I thought. But here's the beef:

All autoreleased objects in the user's callback method will belong to the wrapper's NSAutoreleasePool and hence be released when the callback is completed.

Oops! This means that my m_text string, created implicitly as an autoreleased object by the stringByAppendingFormat message, will be released when logMessage is done and become a zombie. When accessed the next time, the code will crash. The user, of course, certainly and rightfully does not expect this. I myself had to scratch my head a few times before realizing what was going on.

So my question is: How should we deal with autoreleased objects when doing callbacks to user-code from another thread?

I see several possible options. None are perfect and google doesn't help (hence this question).

1. Tell the user "don't create autorelease objects in your callback code". Not good: such objects are often created involuntarily, eg by stringByAppendingFormat and tons of other framework methods. There's no warning other than a later, hard-to-debug crash.
2. Don't have an NSAutoreleasePool. The lack of one will cause warnings if the user tries to create autoreleased objects. Definitely not pretty, but will alert the user to the problem in a robust manner. And the user could "just" add an NSAutoreleasePool of his own to fix the situation. But again: not pretty.
3. No NSAutoreleasePool and run the callback on the main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread. Any new autorelease objects would wind up on the main thread's pool. I think this is safe but would welcome comments - can callbacks always be performed on the main thread, for instance? This approach requires more delicate coding in the wrapper to avoid thread-deadlocks and to wait for the result, but it's my preferred choice so far.

Just to make it clear: Rewriting my own wrapper is no problem. My main priority is creating a solution that will work smooth and seamlessly for a user of the Objective-C framework. Thanks!

Comment: `m_text` is an ivar, right? It's not clear to me why anyone would think that `m_text = <autoreleased object>` is safe. I wouldn't. If I really needed to do something like that, I'd use something along the lines of `m_text = [...[m_text autorelease] ... retain];`

Comment: IOW, I don't think this is your problem. Autorelease scopes are good for objects within your fn defn (- logMessage:) and for values you return but otherwise assuming they're persistent is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's an ivar. And you're right that it may not be "my problem", but it seems an easy mistake to make and one that's I'd really prefer to protect the users of my framework from, if possible. Your suggestion resembles my option 2, ie "don't create an NSAutoreleasePool and let the user discover his mistake that way". It may well be the best option after all.

Comment: This isn't a problem with your autorelease approach. The problem is logMessage as written is fundamentally flawed. It's going to fail any time there's a drain of an enclosing autorelease pool between invokations. The main run loop (modulo optimizations) drains its autorelease pool on every event loop spin, so this would fail there just as badly, wouldn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, yes I guess you're right! Being a newbie Objective-C developer myself I actually didn't think of that :-) I'm still concerned with protecting noobs like me from hurting themselves inadvertedly and it would be great if there was a more controlled way of signalling "you're doing it wrong!" than indirectly by turning their objects into zombies. But again, if they'll be released anyway by the main run loop then I guess my pool doesn't exactly add any harm.

Comment: Yeah. There's not a lot you can do to protect people from retain/release mistakes. That's why Apple put so much effort into Instruments and ARC. BTW, you might want to look at Grand Central Dispatch. It takes away a lot of the pain of threading. It's definitely the "Apple way" as far threading goes into the future.

Comment: I think I see the light now, thanks! I'll look more into GCD, but it's a MacOS 10.6 feature and we'd preferably like the framework to work on as old MacOS versions as possible. If you write up your input as an answer I'll mark it as accepted (unless somebody else comes up with a brilliant idea to "solve" this issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with your autorelease approach. Your approach looks sound.
The problem is `logMessage` as written is fundamentally flawed. It's going to fail any time there's a drain of an enclosing autorelease pool between invokations. The main run loop (modulo optimizations) drains its autorelease pool on every event loop spin, so this would fail there just as badly in that case.

A couple of FWIWs:

```
[Logger logMessage:[[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:message] autorelease]];
```

can be written

```
[Logger logMessage:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:message]];
```

and `[pool drain]` is preferred over `[pool release]`

Comment: Good point about [pool drain]. I thought it was a 10.6 feature, but see now that it was introduced in 10.4. That's pretty old, but it should probably still be subjected to a respondsToSelector-test before invoking it, I guess - better safe than sorry when writing frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what your library does it's hard to recommend an approach. However, calling *performSelectorOnMainThread* is a fairly safe strategy. Given that you wouldn't expect log messages to require any immediate action, it should be fine to wait for the main thread to execute your callback.

Comment: There is one other user-provided interface with two callback methods, for customized Save/Load of data. Those would need to be synchronous so the wrapper would have to wait for them to finish. The library is the iOS/MacOS monitor of EQATEC Analytics, by the way.